# method execute_script don't wait end of script to return value with selenium in python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

i'm trying to make a bot follow for instagram with python and selenium.
*(I am not a developer javascript or python.)*

Anyway, i would like return an array of user with js in execute_script.

and get it with a return in js script.

my python code :

```
ole = []
ole = driver.execute_script("dd = document.getElementsByClassName(\"_8mlbc _t5r8b\"); i = 9; ret = []; before = 0; function need_up() { before = document.getElementsByClassName(\"_4zhc5 _ook48\")[0].title; } function loveu() { if (i == dd.length){return ret;} dd[i].click(); b = setTimeout(need_up, 300);ret.push(before); i++; a = setTimeout(loveu, 400);} return loveu();")
```

for readability here is the javascript code indented :

```
dd = document.getElementsByClassName("_8mlbc _t5r8b");
i = 9;
ret = [];
before = 0;
function get_name_user() { 
    before = document.getElementsByClassName("_4zhc5 _ook48")[0].title;
     } 
function get_array_user() 
{ 
    if (i == dd.length){
        return ret;
    } 
    dd[i].click();
    b = setTimeout(get_name_user, 500);
    ret.push(before);
    i++;
    a = setTimeout(get_array_user, 500);
} 
get_array_user();
return ret;
```

You can try this code on this url *(for exemple)*, it works **ONLY** on firefox: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/happy/

Thank you

Comment: What ist your exact question?

Comment: Yo call get_array_user() asynchronously, so it won't wait for results from the recursive. If you want to wait for the recursive, you need to use callback function.

Comment: Sorry, my question is actually when i try to get return of my code JS i have an array empty because my script run after ole = driver.execute_script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is you call `a = setTimeout(loveu, 400);` asynchronously, so it returns immediately. I think you need to read how to use setTimeout http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval.

I have revised your code by calling `a = loveu();` instead of `a = setTimeout(loveu, 400);` and move it into `function need_up()`.

```
ole = []
script = """
        dd = document.getElementsByClassName("_8mlbc _t5r8b");
        i = 9; ret = []; before = 0;
        function need_up() {
            before = document.getElementsByClassName("_4zhc5 _ook48")[0].title;
            ret.push(before);
            i++;
            a = loveu();
        }
        function loveu() {
            if (i == dd.length){return ret;}
            dd[i].click();
            b = setTimeout(need_up, 5000);
        }
        return loveu();
        """
ole = driver.execute_script(script)
```

Comment: @Fantasim If my answer can fix your problem, please click accept it.