# Is there a way to transform a page loaded by HtmlUnit before it starts executing javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, testing, htmlunit

First I would like to describe the motivation for my question.

I have a complex web page to test with Selenium + HtmlUnit, which launches diverse javascript scripts. The problem which I describe should be quite common.

On the page there is a button to which jQuery binds a click callback (click event handler) after the page is loaded. There is an explicit Wait (this is a Selenium term) for the button to become clickable in the test code. So as soon as the button becomes clickable, it gets clicked by Selenium. Often, however, this happens before jQuery manages to attach to the button the click event handler. In this case the Selenium test fails.

What I thought to do is to preprocess the web page accessed by HtmlUnit before javascript starts executing on the page, injecting some `<script>myownscript()</script>`at the beginning of the page (so that it executes before any other script on that page). Then I would be able to know, controlling certain conditions in the Selenium test code, when exactly the attaching of the click event handler has happened (how I exactly do this, depends on the details of the application). If I make Selenium click the button then, the presence of the click event handler will be guaranteed, and the test would proceed further as planned - with no errors due to the missing click event handler.

Let us leave apart the question whether the idea is a good or a bad one (a much simpler one, of course, would be just introducing a large enough delay in the Selenium test code before trying to click the problematic button, but then there might be a problem with the overall duration of tests, because the problem I described is present on many pages of the application being tested). 
Are there some hooks in Selenium/HtmlUnit which permit to preprocess the page fetched from the server, injecting a script as I described, before javascript starts executing on the page?

Comment: I'm still not clear what is your purpose. As you mentioned, you should add Wait for the element instead. It is quite easy to add the Wait.

Comment: @Buaban I tried to edit the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can use JavaScriptExecutor. You can add a function to do anything you want in the `String script`.

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.id("my-button"));
JavascriptExecutor jsExe = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
String script = "console.log(arguments[0].id); return arguments[0].id";
Object oj = jsExe.executeScript(script, button);
String txt = oj.toString();
System.out.println(txt);
```

Please be careful if you want to use aycn such as setTimeout(), it will return immediately. See an example for async method in my answer at: [method execute_script don't wait end of script to return value with selenium in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252976/method-execute-script-dont-wait-end-of-script-to-return-value-with-selenium-in/35255475#35255475)

Comment: Are you sure that the script you execute this way will be executed **before** any other javascript code embedded in the page? It seems to me that not.

Comment: No, it won't be executed before JS in your application. However, you can use it to add and execute JavaScript on your application. So you can add methods to validate state of your button or control any objects.

Comment: thank you, I was aware of this possibility (polling until click event handler becomes available), but this polling is what I wish to avoid by injecting and executing javascript before any other javascript is run on the page. The idea was that this injected javascript adds another element on the page after the click event handler is bound to the button, and in the test code I wait until this new element becomes available with an explicit Wait. No polling needed.

Comment: Looks like you need to create a Chrome extension. The extension has to do those tasks and provide a method to get state of each objects. You have to add this extension when you create the webdriver. I would like to show you an example but I totally forgot how to do that T-T.